# Why does a div get resized when the position is set to fixed?

Tags: css, css-position

This may sound trivial but I would love to know why this happens. I have the following code:

```css
.fixed {
  position : fixed;
  border : 1px solid black;
  padding : 5px;
  right : 0;
  bottom : 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
I am just a fixed value
</div>
```

Why is it that a div is stretched out wide on both ends when the position : fixed property is not specified. Where as shrinks to the size of the content when specified along with the positioning attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, *the elements are static in position*. And since div is a block element it inherits the width from it's parent and hence it is stretched within the parent's limit.

When an element is positioned, then it is taken out of the regular flow of the elements and hence it cannot inherit any dimension from it's parent (width in this case).

Considering your example, when the div was not positioned then it would have inherited the width from it's parent and hence it had some dimension. When you added **position:fixed** to the style, it was taken out of the regular flow and hence it cannot inherit any dimension. Any dimension will be based on the value you define in the css rule or the default width it's content occupies.

Same holds true for position:absolute too.

Comment: Thanks much! explains a lot